# .Net Framework required for ClickOnce type installers

Tags: vb.net, clickonce

Could you kindly advise if we need to have .NetFrameWork Installed on Client's computer, if we make setup by using ClickOnce technology?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) is a part of .NET Framework 2.0 and later, so yes, you need at least .NET Framework 2.0 installed on a machine in order to use it.  See also [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/winformssetup/thread/2F4C994E-81F7-41AA-9AA5-7025905303AB):

> The installation engine for ClickOnce
>   is in the .NET Frameworks v2.0... as a
>   result, the .**NET Frameworks needs to
>   be on the machine in order to install
>   a ClickOnce deployed application**. The
>   Generic Bootstrapper (setup.exe) will
>   install the .NET Frameworks v2.0
>   before launching the ClickOnce
>   application deployment.

Comment: Well, but I published my application and made a setup.exe
When ran on client's computer, it required to install .Net Framework from the internet.
Why is that?

Comment: Did the client have .NET Framework 2.0 or later?  If not, I'm guessing that's part of the bootstrapper: it ensures that .NET is present before trying to do any ClickOnce deployment

Comment: Did you select the .NET Framework as a prerequisite in the Prerequisites dialog found in the publish page?